# Why does my validation code not work?

Tags: javascript, validation

Basically I'm trying to validate this page with javascript then submit it on to the next page, but the code doesn't work at all. When all fields have been filled in properly, the page doesn't go onto the next page. Validation code is iffy as well.. Filled in height with numbers but it still shows the alert to enter my height in numbers.

Here's a fiddlejs https://jsfiddle.net/aL7q853L/1/

```
function validation() {
    var height, weight;
    height = parseFloat($("#height").val());
    weight = parseFloat($("#weight").val());

    if (validated(height, weight)) {
        document.testform.submit();
    }
}

function validated(height, weight) {
    if (height == "") {
        alert("Please enter your height in meters!");
        $("#height").focus();
        return false;
    }
    else if (weight == "") {
        alert("Please enter your weight in kg!");
        $("#weight").focus();
        return false;
    }
    else if (isNaN(height)) {
        alert("Height must be a number!");
        $("#height").focus();
        return false;
    }
    else if (isNaN(weight)) {
        alert("Weight must be a number!");
        $("#weight").focus();
        return false;
    }
    else if (height <= 130) {
        alert("Height entered must be more than 0 meters!");
        $("#rate").focus();
        return false;
    }
    else if (weight <= 30) {
        alert("Weight entered must be more than 0kg!");
        $("#weight").focus();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

And here's the body

```
<label for="height">Height (In meters)</label>
<input type="text" name="height" id="height" placeholder="enter height in meters">
<label for="weight">Weight</label>
<input type="text" name="weight" id="weight" placeholder="enter weight in KG">
```

Comment: *doesn't work at all* Can you provide a fiddle to show this behaviour? atm your description is kinda ... unspecific ...

Comment: how are you calling the validation?

Comment: could you provide a fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

This works fine.

```
<label for="weight">Weight</label>
<input type="text" onchange="validation()" name="weight" id="weight" placeholder="enter weight in KG">



validation = function () {
    var height, weight;
    height = parseFloat($("#height").val());
    weight = parseFloat($("#weight").val());

    if (validated(height, weight)) {
        document.testform.submit();
    }
}

function validated(height, weight) {
    if (height == "") {
        alert("Please enter your height in meters!");
        $("#height").focus();
        return false;
    } else if (weight == "") {
        alert("Please enter your weight in kg!");
        $("#weight").focus();
        return false;
    } else if (isNaN(height)) {
        alert("Height must be a number!");
        $("#height").focus();
        return false;
    } else if (isNaN(weight)) {
        alert("Weight must be a number!");
        $("#weight").focus();
        return false;
    } else if (height <= 130) {
        alert("Height entered must be more than 0 meters!");
        $("#rate").focus();
        return false;
    } else if (weight <= 30) {
        alert("Weight entered must be more than 0kg!");
        $("#weight").focus();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add

```
$(function() { 
function validation() { 
           var height, weight;
            height = parseFloat($("#height").val());
            weight = parseFloat($("#weight").val());

            if (validated(height, weight)) {
                document.testform.submit();         
            }           
    }
```

in your js script